# Returning First Key in a Nested Dictionary as Column Value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to learn Python, and at the moment I'm working with the Alpaca API to get historical data. I'm working with the raw data, which looks like this:

```
{'SPY': [{'t': '2022-01-03T05:00:00Z', 'o': 476.3, 'h': 477.85, 'l': 473.85, 'c': 477.71, 'v': 72604064, 'n': 534803, 'vw': 476.526964}, {'t': '2022-01-04T05:00:00Z', 'o': 479.22......}
```

What I want to get is it looking like this (just using 4 columns as an example).

```
ticker   t                       o     
SPY      2022-01-03T05:00:00Z    476.3
SPY      2022-01-04T05:00:00Z    479.22
```

I've searched around, and tried using something like json_normalize(my_data), but that just results in the below.

```
                                                 SPY
0  [{'t': '2022-01-03T05:00:00Z', 'o': 476.3, 'h'...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but here

```py
for ticker, ticker_list in my_dict.items():
    for my_dict in ticker_list:
        print(ticker, end="\n")
        for value in my_dict.values():
            print(value, end="\n")
        print()
```

If you want to make it an array instead

```py
result = []
for ticker, ticker_list in my_dict.items():
    for my_dict in ticker_list:
        new_dict = dict(my_dict)
        new_dict["ticker"] = ticker
        result.append(new_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was useful to get my brain thinking about comprehensions.